# Laravel Filter passes and going to requested URL

Tags: php, laravel, filter, eloquent

I am trying to setup laravel filter in my app.

here is my code,

Filter.php

```
Route::filter('userid', function($route,$request,$value)
{
 $id = Auth::user()->id;
 $param = $route->getParameter('id');

    $count = DB::table('timesheets')
    ->where('timesheet_id','=',$param)
    ->where('timesheet_user','=',$id)
    ->count();

   if($count == 1)
   {
    return "here going to requested url";
   }
   else
   {
    return "no permission to this page";
   }

});
```

My Routes,

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'userid:200'),function($route)
 {
    Route::get('edit-timesheet-{id}',array('as'=>'edit_timesheet_form','uses'=>'TimesheetController@editEntry'));
});
```

I am getting the parameters and checking with filter.php was fine.

But when a user click on the **edit-timesheet-756**, if the filter is success, then it needs to continue the execution of the URL, How can i solve this.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

just give blank in true condition.

```
 if($count == 1)
 {
   // here left as blank
 }
 else
 {
  return "no permission to this page";
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

in the filter function you should write :

```
if($count != 1)
 {
  return Redirect::to('another_page');
 }
```

instead of

```
 if($count == 1)
 {
   return "here going to requested url";
 }
 else
 {
   return "no permission to this page";
 }
```

So if the route can pass filter, user will be directed to your edit-timesheet-.. page,  else the user will be redirected to another page like login page or something.

Comment: But i need to continue the execution with request. its getting 404 error

Comment: This should work, just do a redirect if the count id falsy, i.e. `if(!$count) { // redirect...}`

Comment: In the place of  "another_page" you should write a real route of your system.

Comment: But the another page is getting error with 404. I am applying this filter to a group.

Answer (score 2):

In the filter you only worry about the failure. Redirect them or give them an error page if they fail the check.

The request will carry on as intended if the filter doesn't interrupt them.

So, you'd have the filter on the route.
It checks for count. If it fails, show error page, but otherwise don't do anything.

The page loads as expected.